# How to combine 2 dataframes with applying function on the values of the same position

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, concatenation, cosine-similarity

I'm trying to combine 2 dataframes with applying function to values in the same position of 2 dataframes.

Each element in 2 dataframes is list type represented a vector of item[col,row].

```
df1 :

   A      B   
0  vec1   vec2      
1  vec1   vec2      
2  vec1   vec2   

df2 :

   A      B         
0  vec5   vec5     
1  vec6   vec6    
2  vec7   vec7  

function : gensim.matutils.cossim(vec1,vec2)

Expected new_df :
   A                   B
0  cossim(vec1,vec5)   cossim(vec2,vec5)   
1  cossim(vec1,vec6)   cossim(vec2,vec6)   
2  cossim(vec1,vec7)   cossim(vec2,vec7)
```

Following code was implemented by me:

```
for column in df1():
    new_df[column] = df1[column].apply(matutils.cossim(df1[x],df2.loc[0,column]))
```

I am getting the error as:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sqrt'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your own `function` and apply it and change it by [numpy.vectorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity


X = pd.DataFrame([[[0.1,0.1], [0.2,0.2]], [[0.3,0.3], [0.4,0.4]]])
Y = pd.DataFrame([[[0.1,0.1], [0.2,0.2]], [[0.3,0.3], [0.4,0.4]]])

def func(vecx, vecy):
    return cosine_similarity(vecx, vecy)

F = np.vectorize(func)         

print(pd.DataFrame(F(X, Y)))
```

you will get

```
     0    1
0  1.0  1.0
1  1.0  1.0
```